# How to know when a job that require multiple threading has finished?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.3

One thing that I do is:

```
-(void)GrabbingProcess:(void (^)())block;
{
    self.OtherGrabbingIndicator +=1;
    block();
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
        self.OtherGrabbingIndicator -=1;
    });
}
```

Everytime I want to run something that may take a long time in the background, I do something like

[Grabclass grab] GrabbingProcess: ^{
//Do something grab data etc.
}];

There are many such functions and many such data. For example, at first I would grab all the businesses ID. Then I would grab all the details on the businesses on separate thread.

I want to know a time when ALL those threads have finished and post a suitable notification.

The problem with my solution is that after a while, quite often the value of self.OtherGrabbingIndicator hover around 2 or 3 never going down even though all of those thread have finished.

Somehow some of the self.OtherGrabbingIndicator +=1; "leaked" and not matched with self.OtherGrabbingIndicator -=1. I wonder how can that leak ever happen?

Comment: Never *ever* use `dispatch_get_current_queue()`. It's a debugging function and not suitable for use in code.

Comment: Thanks. Can you reference that?

Comment: See the manpage. Under "CAVEATS" it says this function is only for debugging/logging purposes. More specifically, this function only returns the tip of the current queue hierarchy, which may be someone else's private queue.

Comment: Where is this Caveats located?

Comment: Though not exactly answering the question, your comment is good enough. If you turn this as answers I will mark that out unless there are other better answers. Your solution fix my day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run blocks asynchronously and then find out when they're done, the appropriate tool is a [`dispatch_group`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008079-CH2-SW19). You can dispatch blocks onto a specific group and queue using `dispatch_group_async()`, and the group will track when the block is finished. You can then either wait synchronously on the group to finish with `dispatch_group_wait()` or register a block to be invoked when the group is done with `dispatch_group_notify()`.

---

The reason why your solution above doesn't work is because you aren't accessing/mutating the counter in a threadsafe way. Here's a trivial series of events that will cause the problem:

**Start**: self.OtherGrabbingIndicator is 1
**Thread A**: reads self.OtherGrabbingIndicator
**Thread B**: reads self.OtherGrabbingIndicator
**Thread A**: increments the read value and writes back to self.OtherGrabbingIndicator
**Thread B**: increments the read value and writes back to self.OtherGrabbingIndicator
**End**: self.OtherGrabbingIndicator is 2

Even though two threads tried to increment it, only one "succeeded" and you end up losing the other increment. This can also happen during decrement. If you use dispatch groups this problem goes away.

---

As a side note, you should never use `dispatch_get_current_queue()`. This is a debugging function that is never supposed to be used in actual code. The primary reason is because you aren't just running on one queue, you're running on a whole hierarchy of queues simultaneously, but this function can only tell you about the one queue. In addition, you may be running on someone's private queue and you certainly should not be dispatching onto that yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Using dipatch_group is the way to go. By the way self.OtherGrabbingIndicator is atomic.

Comment: @JimThio: The property may be atomic, but that only covers one read, or one write. Your code is doing a read + write, which cannot possibly be atomic at the property level. You need a higher-level synchronization to do that (e.g. gating access to the property with a lock or a dispatch queue).